# browsersync reload when a nunjucks partial file is modified

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, nunjucks

I have a gulp task as following:

```
gulp.task("nunjucks", () => {
  return gulp
    .src([src_folder + "pages/**/*.njk"])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(
      data(() =>
        JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(src_folder + "datas/dist/data.json"))
      )
    )
    .pipe(nunjucks())
    .pipe(beautify.html({ indent_size: 2 }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist_folder))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({match: '**/*.html'}));
 });

gulp.watch([src_folder + '**/*.njk'], gulp.series("nunjucks")).on("change", browserSync.reload);
```

and my project structures look like this:

[image]

atoms, molecules and organisms contains nunjucks partials.

The problem I have is that whenever I update a partial file (ex: organisms/partial1.njk), my task detects changes on all the files inside `pages` (the path I provided for the task src), as you can see here :

[image]

I only want to reload the files that includes this partial and not all the files.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Its not up to your gulp task to know which one of your Nunjuck pages contain partials.  Perhaps if you re-group your .njk files within your Pages folder, you could then better manage what gets reloaded. The following is untested, but hopefully conveys the idea...

```
pages/
  - init/
  - other-stuff/
```

You could then update the src from your gulp task to something like so...

```js
 gulp.src([
      '!pages/other-stuff/**/*',
      'pages/init/**/*.njk'
    ])
```